# AngularJS, how to bind a variable to concatenation of two other bound variables?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to build an AngularJS practice app, in which, the user will concatenate a url from multiple inputs, i.e. protocol, domain, path, param1, param2, param3... etc.

And the app will create a link to the url:

```
<a>{{protocol}}://{{domain}}{{path}}?{{param1}}&{{param2}}&{{param3}}</a>
```

Above url is used twice. Once on the href attribute, as well as the actual text. Now what I want to do is something like:

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{url}}</a>
```

But I am not sure where to assign url.
I tried below, and it worked, but doesn't seem correct.

```
<a href='{{url = protocol+"://"+domain+path+"?"+param1+"&"+param2+"&"+param3}}'>{{url}}</a>
```

Assuming that `url` is used many times in the app, where would be the most appropriate place to assign `url`?

Comment: try using `ng-init` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit Also, you might wanna use ng-href instead of href.

Comment: Hello, can't you store it inside your scope with $scope.url = concanated url; and then user {{url}} inside your controller?

Comment: Hi @askkirati, but if I do that, when user changes one of the variables, url didn't get updated... $scope.url = concatenated url seemed to only happen once during init. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @AdityaJain, samething, ng-init only does it once...

Comment: agreed, I think best solution is what @mikel provided.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You shouldn't assign scope variables in the view (the HTML) - it's only for reading them.

To make a new variable from inputs, add a ng-model to each of them and then in the controller define a method that makes a $scope variable from them e.g.

Your HTML form:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <input type="text" ng-model="urlParts.protocol">
    <input type="text" ng-model="urlParts.domain">
    <!-- etc -->
    <a ng-href="{{makeUrl()}}">{{makeUrl()}}</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.urlParts = {};
    $scope.urlParts.protocol = ""; 
    $scope.urlParts.domain = ""; 
    // etc... 
    // These values will be updated when the user types in the input boxes

    $scope.makeUrl = function() {
      return $scope.urlParts.protocol + "://" + $scope.urlParts.domain + $scope.urlParts.path + "?" + $scope.urlParts.param1 + "&" + $scope.urlParts.param2 + "&" + $scope.urlParts.param3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you used `ng-href` instead of regular `href`?

Comment: Duh! that's so simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another similar approach is to use ng-init directive to create a dynamic property which represents the concatenation of all those properties. You can call the function or just concatenate inline.

```
 <a ng-init="urlParts.url=makeUrl()" 
ng-href="urlParts.url">{{urlParts.url}}
</a>

<a ng-init="urlParts.url=urlParts.protocol + '://' + $scope.urlParts.domain..." 
    ng-href="urlParts.url">{{urlParts.url}}
    </a>
```

Reference:
http://www.ozkary.com/2015/03/angularjs-ng-model-concatenate-model.html

Try It: http://plnkr.co/edit/PSvwCE?p=info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a dynamic url with `href` then you can manipulate you URL in `ng-click` or `ng-mousedown` event and bind to target element.

JS:

```
var goToLinkedPage = function (event, basePath, param1, param2, param 3) {
    var newState = basePath + "?" + param1 + "&" + param2 + "&" + param3;
    jQuery(event.target).attr('href',newState);
};
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-mousedown="goToLinkedPage($event, basePath, param1, param2, param3)"> Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this binding expression to concatenation of more than two scope variables in HTML.

```
{{UserData.FirstName + ' ' + UserData.MiddleName + ' ' + UserData.LastName}}
```

If you want to do this inside any attribute, Just write like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="UserData.FirstName + ' ' + UserData.MiddleName + ' ' + UserData.LastName">
```