# 2 GET method forming for a single resource in AngularJS image fetch

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, performance

Following is my `AngularJS` table code, which is filling the `tr`s like -

```
<tbody class="no-bd-y">
  <tr ng-repeat="emp in empData">
    <td>{{emp.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.last_name}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{siteurl}}:3030/public/{{emp.prof_image}}" width="120" height="120" ng-if="emp.prof_image" class="img-responsive"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now the problem is when I firebug the page, **2** URLs are formed for every image -

> http://example.com:8000/%7B%7Bsiteurl%7D%7D:3030/public/%7B%7Bemp.prof_image%7D%7D
>
> http://example.com:3030/public/a1419c564308370f8d4817b7885ce031.png

Console -

[image: Going On]

As you can see now, every image is forming `2 GET` and as previous one is not correct the page load time increase. Let me know how could I fix this problem ?

**EDIT**

Following is my controller code -

```
angular.module("app").controller("MyController", function($scope, $location, SessionService, $http) {
    $scope.user = SessionService.currentUser;
    $scope.siteurl = $location.absUrl().split(":8000/")[0];

    // Get user listing
    $http.get("/api/getempl").then(function(response){
        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            $scope.empData = response.data.data;       
        }
        else {
            console.log('400');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: can you show us your controller or scope called emp  ?

Comment: @Vladimir yeah sure..let me add that code

Comment: @Vladimir Please find my edit

Comment: Try to make this function inside module app and return the result like it explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184026/angularjs-how-to-bind-a-variable-to-concatenation-of-two-other-bound-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `src` directly, and since angular doesn't run before the dom is ready it is trying to fetch the src.  Use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead which doesn't set the src attribute until angular can process it.

```
<img ng-src="{{siteurl}}:3030/public/{{emp.prof_image}}"...
```

Comment: Wow ..this fixed my problem..+1 and a green tick

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ng-src`, it should help